# Returning the top x of a partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am in need of partitioning the rows I get back and only taking the top 2 of a specific partitions retrieving only the last 2 (based on UpdatedOn column) but return all rows for the rest. The partitions will be created off of one column (column Type below) that may have only a few combinations.

- One partition could have a value of 1.
- Second partition could have a value of 2.
- Third partition could have a value of 4.
- Fourth partition will be NULL (account for > 95% of all the data)

I need to return the top 2 of each NON-NULL partition (column Type below) and all the data for the partition (Type) that has NULL within that partition.

I've started with the following (it doesn't run yet) but got stuck:

```
SELECT Sort, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.Type ORDER BY p.UpdatedON DESC) AS RN, 
       u.Column1, u.Column2, u.Type 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 u 
ON u.Id = p.Id 
WHERE p.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id From Table 3 Where Id = 'x') 
ORDER BY p.Sort DESC, p.UpdatedOn DESC
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: so Table 1 contains a million records with 95% of data being under Type where its value is NULL. I just need the top 2 of all the other partitions. So I expect say 950,006 rows back. 950,000 will be for the partition where Type  IS NULL and the 6 rows for the other 3 partitions being on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (replace `MyTable` with the tables/joins you are actually selecting from, and `ID` with the column(s) you need in your results):

```
select type, updatedon, ID from
    (select *, row_number() over (partition by type order by Updatedon desc) RN from MyTable) a
where a.RN <= 2
or type is null
```

It's very similar to what you had already - just added some logic wrapped around your initial `partition`.

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12ecd/2/0